# Add silent track to WebM video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

FFMPEG documentation says this can be achieved by doing something similar to the following:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i $media -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac $output`

However when i try this with a WebM video I get the following error:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1
```

I there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AAC is not a compatible codec for WebM. You can simply drop `-c:a aac` and FFmpeg will select the default audio codec for the output format. Opus (`libopus`) and Vorbis (`libvorbis`) are acceptable audio codecs for WebM.